# Algorithm used by browser for searching words in the webpage

Tags: algorithm, browser, data-structures

Which data structure or algorithm is used in browsers to search for a word? Will the browsers construct a trie or suffix tree?

Thank you
Bala

Comment: Do you mean when you press Ctrl+F and type in a word to search for on that individual page?

Comment: @James Yes, the ctrl+F option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searching with a trie/suffix tree is fast -- but building the trie to start with is considerably slower. That means they only make sense when you *expect* to carry out a large number of searches over the same data, so you can amortize the time to build the trie over many searches.

The average number of searches inside a web page is probably fractional (i.e. you expect the user to load several pages before doing a search even once). Even when you do search a page, doing a lot of searches in the same page is probably pretty rare.

That means a linear search will almost always be substantially *more* efficient overall than a trie or suffix tree. My guess is that if they bother optimizing it beyond a simple call to `strstr()` that they only go as far as something in the Boyer-Moore family of string searching. Given the number of searches you expect in a web page, this will normally *finish* them all before you could just do the initial build of the trie, so you could *start* searching with it.

For interactive use, your primary concern is producing results fast enough to appear instantaneous. That generally means results within 100ms or so. With a good implementation of Boyer-Moore-Horspool, that's enough time to search an amount of text that would be *insane* to include in a single web page (on the order of hundreds of megabytes or gigabytes).

If you want to put it to the test, I'd recommend Ray Gardner's implementation of Boyer-Moore-Horspool (Bmhsrch.C, from Bob Stout's [Snippets](http://c.snippets.org/browser.php) site). I'd truly *hate* to see a web page large enough to keep it occupied for even 20 ms, not to mention 100 (though I'm the first to admit this particular implementation is exceptionally fast).

Comment: Funny, WebKit even contains a comment `// FIXME: Can we do Boyer-Moore or equivalent instead for speed?` http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/WebCore/editing/TextIterator.cpp?rev=34822#L1378

Answer (score 3):

Web pages are usually not large enough to need sophisticated search algorithms, at least on the first scan. I mean that you can probably find any word with a simple linear search in just a few ms. An optimization could be to build a trie during the first scan and then use it for subsequent searches.

Overall, I don't think this is one of the big issues in browser algorithms.

Comment: I don't agree with you that linear scan will be used, because most browsers will highlight all the occurrences of the word as you type, and I don't think linear scan makes sense here. It could be that, based on the size of the web page, linear scan or trie will be used.

Comment: @Algorist: how would highlighting the words make linear scan obsolete? To build a trie you still have to scan linearly at least once, so you just as well can use it for finding the first results

Comment: But there is a difference between doing linear scan once..and doing it for every search word.

Comment: @Algorist: and this is why I wrote the last sentence in the first paragraph of my answer

Answer (score 3):

To understand why a linear scan is fast enough, consider how much more complex page rendering is (which obviously requires at least a linear scan of the HTML) and how fast it is done. I think the browser will spend a lot more time highlighting occurences than searching for them, anyways.

Also, the search may be done incrementally. Say, I'm searching for "algorithm". When I type "a", the browser might find (or asynchronously start searching for) the occurences of the letter "a" and subsequent symbols only refine the current findings.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of regular expressions is just more than enough. Take a look at various online tools.